# bootstrap bottom-fixed but if container height is bigger than browser, align at end

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I know there is a bottom-fixed class in bootstrap for aligning divs at bottom.

But what If I want to have something like this:

1. scenario: the container with page-content is small (doesn't fit the whole height of the browser-window) -> align the div at the bottom.

   - Example: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/bottom-footer-demo.htm
2. scenario: the container with page-content is bigger than the browser-height. I want to align the div staight after the container-div. (not fixed at the bottom. it's more fixed at the bottom of the html-page)

   - Example: http://www.productivedreams.com/

is there a built-in functionality of bootstrap to do this?

Comment: I am having trouble understanding your second point.  Can you explain further?

Comment: of course (it was bit late in the night, so I can understand you) I've edited the post.